# Convention for generators of monoids - is $ \left\{x^n \right\} _{n\geq 0}$ freely generated by $x$?

Tags: terminology, monoid

I'm trying to understand whether the multiplicative monoid $ \left\{x^n \right\} _{n\geq 0}$ freely generated by $x$ or $1,x$. So for monoids, are "zeroth powers" included in generating sets or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monoid is supposed to have an identity element, which is with free generation considered as the empty string. Hence your example translates to the free monoid on the letter $x$.